# Smf image upload troubles

Tags: php, upload, smf, simple-machines-forum

Folks, kindly help me.
Have the following issue with `smf 2.0.4` (latest)
User cannot upload image even the smallest one. Other file extensions pass well.
Tried the following:
tracking `$_FILES` - no errors,
uploading as admin, adding extra attachment folder, checking server free space, forum setting for attachment limits set to maximum. Also have increased all possible `php.ini` limits. Chdmod is 755 for all folder, tried also 777 for attachments folder.
Kindly tell me what could be wrong ?
my phpinfo is here http://tinyurl.com/bqxchl8

The error message is as follows:
`Your attachment couldn't be saved. This might happen because it took too long to upload or the file is bigger than the server will allow.

Please consult your server administrator for more information.`

Answer (score 0):

3 months later, but wth...

Check you SMF Admin, where the `Attachments and Avatars` category `Attachment Settings` is located, and be sure that the image file you are uploading has a file extension that is located within the comma separated list for the `Allowed attachment extensions` setting.

There are other setting in there that you will need to change as well, such as:

`Max attachment folder space`
`Max attachment size per post`
`Max size per attachment`
`Max number of attachments per post`

Also, make sure `Perform extensive security checks on uploaded image attachments` setting is UNCHECKED.  This can cause rejected image attachments, since this is somewhat buggy in SMF.

If you set all of these settings to `0`, than it will be UNLIMITED!  Therefore, no restrictions whatsoever on these.

If you still have a problem uploading image files, than go back to the `Admin -> Attachments and Avatars -> Attachment Settings` and uncheck:  `Re-encode potentially dangerous image attachments`

Good Luck and hopefully this helps.